# regEx matching a curly brace don't matched any way I try

Tags: python, regex

solving a trivial task of finding the start of a body of a .php function, I'm not able to get a regEx match however I tried. Here's what I supposed to do the job:

```
import re
print re.search(r"addToHead(){", "addToHead(){\n\tcode...").group()
# addToHead is the function I'm looking for.
  # --> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
print re.search(r"addToHead()\{", "addToHead(){\n\tcode...").group()
  # Nor backslashing or double backslash works.
print re.search(r"addToHead()[\{]", "addToHead(){\n\tcode...").group()
print re.search(r"addToHead()[\x7b]", "addToHead(){\n\tcode...").group()
# Noting works...am I missing something??
```

Also I tried with `re.DOTALL` with the same unpleasant result. Do I sit on my nerve? Or a bug..?

Answer (score 1):

Brackets `()` are used to logically group the matched string in regular expression. Basically, they have special meaning in regular expressions. So you have to escape the brackets `()` like `\(\)`.

```
print re.search(r"addToHead\(\){", "addToHead(){\n\tcode...").group()
```

**Output**

```
addToHead(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now, just a minute after I posted the question I found it, it's not with the curly brace, but the standard brackets...well, I should likely delete my question, but [Meta-question] would I be able to access it as a record of my past blindness?

Comment: Let it be. Other people who made the same mistake might learn from this. :)